# jquery can't update text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user clicks the `onsite` radio button the correct value appears in the `td` with the class `job_num_value` but I also want it in the text input but it remains blank and I can't work out for the life of me why?

The table elements

```
<td>Job Num:
    <input type="text" name="job_num_val_hidden" id="job_num_val_hidden" value=""/>
</td>
<td id="job_num" width="69" class="job_num_value create_input_td"></td>
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    job_num_val = '<? echo $new_job_num; ?>';
    $('#onsite').on("click", function() {
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.job_order_num').css('display', 'table-row');
            $('.job_num_value').html(job_num_val); 
            $('#job_num_value_hidden').val(job_num_val); 
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your dom id is `job_num_val_hidden`, but you query by `#job_num_value_hidden`.

Comment: doh!, thanks will accept when it lets me